# What creates $HOME/.local/share/keyrings?

Tags: xdg-base-directory

According to the [XDG Base Directory Spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html),

> `$XDG_DATA_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user specific data files should be stored. If `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.local/share` should be used.

I set `$XDG_DATA_HOME` to `$HOME/AppData` in my `.profile`.  So far, everything seems to respect this except that something keeps creating files under `$HOME/.local/share/keyrings`.  What creates these files, or how can I find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently a [bug in `gnome-keyring`](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686934).  The workaround suggested in [comment #6](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686934#c6) does not work.

Comment: Hi @MicrosoftFree, Please note that you are allowed to mark your own answer as being correct.

Comment: @Tshilidzi Only after two days.

Comment: oh, I didnt know that, cool